# Fixture side box?

Tags: light-fixture

Does anyone have any idea what is this side (maybe converter) attached to the side of the fixture.
The fixture has the conventional 2 black/white and ground wiring.
In addition, one red and white, I would say 18 gauge, wiring connected to that side box.
Cannot tell what is connected to that wiring.

[image]

Comment: [Doorbell Transformer](https://www.google.com/search?q=doorbell+transformer&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS840US840&sxsrf=ALeKk01yeb7dvnzLuipyt-YJ5aDMAWP9zg:1595804682621&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ4vPZg-zqAhVQn-AKHbILDv8Q_AUoAnoECAwQBA&biw=2560&bih=937)

Comment: 18 awg red and white is quite common for doorbell circuits, the red white wires are low voltage and go to the chime / furnace  switch or thermostat. The “high voltage side is 120v , black hot, white neutral and the metal box is the ground.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a normal transformer for a doorbell or furnace. I would guess , doorbell with most homes but a home with a gas furnace and fan they are also normal.

Comment: My furnace has the transformer for the thermostat signal inside the housing somewhere.